# overloading operator<< to change member variable

Tags: c++, class, operator-keyword

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class A {
  public:
    A() {};
    A& operator<< (A& a, unsigned int i);

  private:
    vector<int> abc;
}
```

I want to offer the ability to add objects to `abc` using an operator:

```
A a();
a << 3,4,5; // should do the same as several calls of abc.push_back(i)
```

I know that I have to overload the `<<` operator, do I also have to overload the `,` operator?

How would the actual method look like?

Comment: Can't you just do `a << 3 << 4 << 5`?

Comment: At first this could also suffice. The `,` operator could be a good exercise though. I still have problems on how to actually implement this method. Last I tried I got some errors telling me about an `invalid number of operands`.

Comment: That's because you made `operator <<` a member function and you made it accept 2 arguments. If you make it a member, just specify one argument (`int`), the first one is implicit. Otherwise, declare it as a `friend` function accepting 2 arguments

Comment: Is there an obfuscated C++ contest that we're supposed to help you win?

Comment: The `a << 3,4,5;` idea would hardly pass my review. Even just << would need fair support

Comment: @JamesKanze no contest, just personal interest. I have been doing some lisp programming lately. I like how you can easily define a DSL there. Maybe that is why I wanted to look into this stuff. For *real* code I would probably prefer `a << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5`, which in my opinion is far more concise than several `push_backs`.

Comment: @j.dog C++11 provides for this quite well with list initialization.  Otherwise, in older C++, I'd go for something like 'a.add( 2 ).add( 3 ).add( 4 ).add( 5 )`, which works well if `add` returns a reference to the container.  But `<<` implies formatting, so doesn't see, appropriate here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep the aspect of `a << 1, 2, 3` you could change your overloading of `operator<<` to accept an `initializer_list` of `int`, instead of a single `int`.

```
#include <initializer_list>

class A {
    public:
    A() {};
    A& operator<< (std::initializer_list<int> values);

    private:
    vector<int> abc;
}
```

Then implement it like:

```
A& A::operator<< (std::initializer_list<int> values)
{
    for(const auto& value : values)
        abc.push_back(value);
    return *this;
}
```

And simply use it as follows :

```
A a;
a << {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

The only thing you need to make sure is you have a C++11 compliant compiler that provides these features.

Comment: Very good point.  The problem is much better solved using initializer lists (supposing you have C++11).

Comment: Looks like a really good way to do this! One question according to @AndyProwls comment to my original post, the `operator<<` function would only need one argument?

Comment: Effectively I changed the method's signature because it's a member, and I added the return statement. I hope it is correct now, but tell me if there are corrections to do.

Answer (score 9):

Never, ever, ever overload the `,` operator in C++. The language allows for it, but you can't do it and preserve the expected behavior of the operator. (In particular, the comma operator is a sequence point in C++: the compiler guarantees that the left-hand expression will be evaluated before the right-hand expression. If you overload it, there are no longer any guarantees about which expression will be evaluated first.)

You want to use multiple invocations of your stream insertion operator to insert multiple objects.

(For completeness: th eother C++ operators you should never overload are `&&` and `||`. Again, it's impossible to provide the behavior that client code will expect (short circuiting, in this case)).

Comment: Yada yada. Boost did it, so can we :)

Comment: Also, don't overload unary `&`.

Comment: @jrok Boost is _not_ an example to follow, at least not for a lot of components.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I tend to agree, but I actually found a case where it made sense.  Smart pointers, but to a C interface: the pointer behaves (sort of) like a `char*`, so it's `operator&` returns a `char**`.  (And while it seemed like a good idea at the time, I'm not fully convinced.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree 100% in principle, but the Allocator and Iterator interfaces just aren't mature enough. When the Standard is confident enough to specify that referencing a `std::vector< bool >::reference` produces a bit-pointer, then it will be safe for mere mortal users to do so.

Comment: @JamesKanze (By the way, a few years ago I went as far as starting to compile a list of additional requirements for Allocator and containers, but stopped when I got the sense that the general idea had been abandoned as impractical by the committee. I'm interested to know if that's untrue.)

Answer (score 1):

The Eigen library implements this syntax. Not sure if that's where you're coming from.

Eigen is an expression template library. It defines operators and functions which appear to do things, but are just factories for proxy objects. The proxies form compile-time, and sometimes runtime data structures which decide when and how a computation should be done.

To realize this syntax, you'll need proxy objects. Think of it analogously to `std::ostream`. `a << 3` returns a proxy "stream" object, which then overloads `operator ,` to enable the `, 4, 5` part. The proxy could just as well overload `operator<<`, in which case the syntax would be `a << 3 << 4 << 5`. This is arguably cleaner, but Eigen is a math- and operator-overloading-intensive library, and `,` has a special position as the lowest-precedence operator, which reduces the possibility of precedence mistakes in such an initialization as `a << 3, true? 4 : 42, 5`.

Long story short, you should probably stick to just `operator<<` even if you do it this way.

```
class A {
  public:
    A() {};

    inserter operator << (A& a, unsigned int i) {
      inserter ret( * this );
      ret , i;
      return ret;
    }

  private:
    vector<int> abc;

    struct inserter {
      A &client;

      inserter( A &in_client ) : client( in_client ) {}

      inserter &operator , ( int x ) {
        client.abc.push_back( x );
        return this;
      }
    };
    friend struct inserter;
};
```

Comment: This way the general approach I had in mind but couldn't put into code. :) Thank you!