# How do I use this debug macro?

Tags: c++, macros

```
using namespace std;
#ifdef DEBUG
     #define debug(args...)            {dbg,args; cerr<<endl;}
#else
     #define debug(args...)              // Just strip off all debug tokens
#endif

struct debugger
{
    template<typename T> debugger& operator , (const T& v)
    {    
        cerr<<v<<" ";    
        return *this;    
    }
} dbg;


int main(){
    int a=1,b=2,c=3;
    debugger(a,b,c);
}
```

I found this debug macro and I am trying to use this but this isn't working. I am getting following error:

```
ubuntu:~ g++ -DEBUG a.cpp -o a
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:81:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘debugger::debugger(int&, int&, int&)’
a.cpp:81:16: note: candidates are:
a.cpp:62:8: note: debugger::debugger()
a.cpp:62:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 3 provided
a.cpp:62:8: note: debugger::debugger(const debugger&)
a.cpp:62:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

Comment: Try `debug(a, b, c);`

Comment: Shouldn't it be  g++ -DDEBUG a.cpp -o a instead of g++ -DEBUG a.cpp -o a

Comment: Your command-line parameter should be -DDEBUG -- the -D is "define". RIght now you're defining "EBUG".

Comment: @RedX It doesn't give any error on compilation but doesn't print anything.

Comment: Also, don't overload the comma operator. It's just a bad idea. See my answer here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16884473/279130

Comment: @drescherjm Yes that solved the problem along with calling debug instead of debugger. One more doubt right now it is only printing the value of the variable. Can I modify it to print the name of the variable too?

Comment: @jwismar So what's the alternative? I am not much familiar with operator overloading. Can I replace it with any other special characters?

Comment: You should use a variadic template instead of overloading the comma operator. Depending on how you handle this, you will either crash MSVC or generate lots of functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply try by using:-

```
debug(a, b, c);
```

Also  you have to change the command line `-DDEBUG -- the -D is "define"`. Presently you're defining `"EBUG"`.

Comment: and -DDEBUG instead of defining EBUG, which won't print anything (see comments)